# Golang App not sending traces to Otel Collector

Tags: go, datadog, open-telemetry

I am trying to set up tracing in my project using OpenTelemetry and Datadog. I am running an Otel collector using Docker on my machine and the collector exports data to a Datadog backend. I also have a Go web server running locally and I am attempting to send traces to the Otel backend, but it does not seem to be working.

My Otel config file looks like this:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: "localhost:4317"

processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 10s

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      key: <API-KEY>
      site: <SITE>

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

service:
  pipelines:    
    traces:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ datadog ]
    metrics:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ datadog ]
```

The Otel logs indicate that it is connecting to the exporter:

```
API key validation successful..... Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
```

In my code, the following is used to set up the tracing:

```
func SetupTracer(ctx context.Context) (func() error, trace.Tracer) {
    grpcClient := otlptracegrpc.NewClient(
        otlptracegrpc.WithInsecure(),
        otlptracegrpc.WithEndpoint("127.0.0.1:4317"))

    exporter, err:=  otlptrace.New(ctx, grpcClient)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to initialize exporter: %v", err)
    }

    openTelResource, err := resource.New(
        ctx,
        resource.WithAttributes(semconv.ServiceNameKey.String(ServiceName)),
    )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error resource ", err)
    }
    traceProvider:=  sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.ParentBased(sdktrace.AlwaysSample())),
        sdktrace.WithSpanProcessor(sdktrace.NewBatchSpanProcessor(exporter)),
        sdktrace.WithResource(openTelResource),
    )

    otel.SetTracerProvider(traceProvider)

    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(
        propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(
            propagation.TraceContext{},
            propagation.Baggage{},
        ),
    )

    return func() error {
        return traceProvider.Shutdown(ctx)
    }, traceProvider.Tracer(ServiceName, trace.WithInstrumentationVersion(ServiceVersion))
}
```

This is how the tracer is set up and used:

```
shutdown, tracer := instrumentation.SetupTracer(ctx)
defer shutdown()

_, span := tracer.Start(r.Context(), "do-something")
// do something
span.End()
```

I am getting the following error on from my service

```
max retry time elapsed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp
127.0.0.1:4317: connect: connection refused"
```

Comment: Can you connect to the collector with another too like telnet or netcat? If not, then the problem is unrelated to Go and you likely need to do something about your docker networking setup.

Comment: Don't use localhost/127.0.0.1.